Word macro to replace the paragraph marks with line break symbols
Good day,
I need to replace the paragraph marks with line break symbols in all the POETRY lines except the last one in each poetry extract with style "quote poet".
When there is one line only there should be no change.
Here is a sample text, RS Vol 1 B1 (2022 04 09) - import 3d.docx linked https://drive.proton.me/urls/YHMZ9BCNGM#jt39eAAjcpgq
I have created a Word macro to do it but it does not work well.
Can someone help ?
Here is the code:
Sub ParaBreakToLineBreak()
'
' ParaBreakToLineBreak Macro
' ParaBreakToLineBreak Style = "quote poet"     Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
'

    ' Go to start of document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

Do

For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("quote poet")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^$"
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    
    If Paragraph.Next.Style = "quote poet" Then
                
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("quote poet")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("quote poet")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^l"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With
      
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    
    Else
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'   Paragraph.Next.Style = "Body Text First Indent1"
    
    End If
  
    Next
    
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        
    Loop Until Selection.Range.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End

End Sub


Try the following:
Sub ParaBreakToLineBreak()
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Format = True
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("quote poet")
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Style = "quote poet" Then
                .Characters.Last = Chr(11)
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub


Dear Timothy, Thank you so much. It works perfect.

@SergeyStanovykh - @ - please see What should I do when someone answers my question?
